# OrmLite – Prevent automatic database changes when adding to or removing from a ForeignCollection

Tags: ormlite, foreign-collection

Currently, I am using OrmLite and I have three objects A, B, and C.  A contains a ForeignCollection of B, and B contains a  ForeignCollection of C.  Anytime I add an element to the ForeignCollections an insert statement is instantly executed.  A delete statement is instantly executed anytime I remove an element.

I would like to add/remove without the statements being executed until I either create or update A.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to add/remove without the statements being executed until I either create or update A. Is this possible?

There is no way to do this currently.  The lazy-loaded collection doesn't even store items in itself so the idea of caching changes for later is not possible.

You could do this on your own however.  You could keep a list of items in the entity and then override the `dao.create(...)` and `dao.update(...)` methods to call `collection.addAll(...)` if there are any cached items in your special collection.

```
private List<Item> foreignItemsToAdd;
...
private void addForeignItem(Item item) {
   if (foreignItemsToAdd == null) {
       foreignItemsToAdd = new ArrayList<Item>();
   }
}
```

Then the dao would have something like:

```
@Override
public int create(ParentItem parent) throws SQLException {
    if (parent.getForeignItemsToAdd() != null) {
        parent.getForeignItems().addAll(parent.getForeignItemsToAdd());
    }
    return super.create(parent);
}
```